# JPEG encoding store encoded data

Tags: image, encoding, bitmap, jpeg

I'm implementing the JPEG encoding and writing it in a JFIF container.

The original image (bitmap):

[image: original bitmap (bmp)]

My encoded JPEG:

[image]

encoded JPEG with The Gimp (quality 50 and basic settings):

[image]

I'm trying to figure out the problem and my guess is it is in the encoded data itself and not in the JFIF header.

The steps (basic overview) that I've done in the encoding:

1. RGB to YCbCr
2. Split each Y, Cb and Cr information in MCU's (8x8 blocks). I did not do any subsampling on the Cb and Cr parts as I have not studied yet how this exactly works. (blocks = MCU's)
3. Apply DCT to all blocks of Y, Cb and Cr
4. Quantization for all blocks of Y, Cb and Cr
5. Vectorize (1x64 array) all blocks of Y, Cb and Cr (Zig-Zag)
6. Apply DPCM (DC) and RLE (AC) on all blocks of Y, Cb and Cr.
7. Do Huffman magic and save data.

For the last step (7) I process the Y, Cb and Cr blocks as follow:

1. Process 8x8 Block 1 of Y
2. Process 8x8 Block 1 of Cb
3. Process 8x8 Block 1 of Cr
4. Process 8x8 Block 2 of Y
5. Process 8x8 Block 2 of Cb
6. Process 8x8 Block 2 of Cr
7. Process 8x8 Block 3 of Y
8. ...

So my data is currently stored as Y Cb Cr Y Cb Cr Y Cb Cr Y Cb ...
**Is this correct?**

or should data of Y, Cb and Cr be processed as following:

```
Y Y Y Y ... Yn  Cb Cb Cb .... Cbn  Cr Cr Cr Cr .... Crn
```

My question (as I guess the mistake is in the encoding of the data):

**How do you store the encoded data itself?**

Trying to figure out why my JPEG encoded output is bigger and not showing correctly. Any help is welcome.

Comment: There is some [relatively] simple JPEG source code here:
http://www.colosseumbuilders.com/sourcecode/index.html
What you need to do is take some simple images and compare how your encoder works at each step.

Comment: Thanks. That JPEGDUMP app would be handy, but not available anymore.

Comment: ok it is included in the lib. didn't see that :)

Comment: The JPEG file format has vertical and horizontal sampling factors - these dictate the sequence of component MCUs in the scan data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I wrote a JPEG encoder from scratch in C.
So I use [bmptoppm](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep557/06au/tools/bmptojpeg.html) to convert BMP to JPG and use this JPG image as a reference.
Open the reference image and the incorrect resultant one (append .hex to the file name, e.g. **reference.jpg.hex** and **myImage.jpg.hex**) in your text editor (I use Sublime Text).
Firstly, make sure the headers of two JPG files are the same.
Then navigate to the encoded data.
Find out where the difference is and from which 8 X 8 pixel block the difference derives.
Now look into the block and find out which encoding step is incorrect.

My problem was that there was a wrong value in the Huffman table.
So when I first tried to encode the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZMXN.png) on the left, I got the one on the right.
My encoder is only for gray-scale, so I am not sure about the sequence of Y, Cb and Cr.

Hopefully, you can fix the error by following the steps.